# Angular JS - How do I define new dependency - Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs, node.js, laravel-5.1

I am trying to use [this package](https://github.com/eddiemoore/angular-spotify) in a Laravel app.

I have successfully installed with npm but when I try to inject the dependency in my controller I am getting this error;

Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider

This is in my app.js;

```
var app = angular.module('spotify', ['spotify']);

app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', 'Spotify', function ($scope, Spotify) {

}]);
```

I am sure it's something simple but am stuck.  Has else tried this or have a suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your capitalization. 'spotify' != 'Spotify'.

Comment: you can't name your app the same name as your module. `angular.module('myApp', 'spotify');` https://github.com/eddiemoore/angular-spotify/blob/master/examples/main.controller.js

Comment: Thanks for both the replies.  Looks like it was the duplicate name issue.  Much appreciated!